# The view companies.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, httpresponse

I am still learning and none of the other questions answer my question, why do I have to have an HTTP Response?

```
def view(request):
        namesTickers = Company.objects.all().values('name', 'ticker')
        names, tickers = [], []
        for nameTicker in namesTickers:
                names.append(nameTicker['name']) 
                tickers.append(nameTicker['ticker']) 
        nameTickerDict = dict(zip(names, tickers))
        print nameTickerDict

        if 'ticker' in request.POST and request.POST['ticker']:
                q = request.POST['ticker']

                context = {}
                context['companies'] = json.dumps(nameTickerDict)
                context['companyInfo'] = Company.objects.filter(ticker__icontains=q)
                context['financial'] = Financials.objects.filter(ticker__icontains=q).order_by('-year')

                return render( request, "companies/view.html",[context])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because HTTP is a request/response mechanism. You get a request and you must respond to it. It doesn’t have to be a *successful* response, though. If you cannot respond meaningfully without a `ticker`, you may return an error page instead. Or, if you have a form where the user enters a ticker and submits that to your `view`, then you probably want to return the user back to the same form but with an error message. If that is the case, Django’s [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) will help you.